# Access violation reading location in reading Array

Tags: c++

I'm using a program to execute another program.In this case it's an .exe of selection sort.So main program calls the exe by passing array generated in main program.When selection sort exe executes, there is an error saying access violation reading location.I'll put the code of exe.

error occurs in the line 'min=array[i];'

```
    int _tmain(int *array,int length)
    {
    int i,j,min,minLoc;

    for(i=0;i<(length-1);i++)
    {
        minLoc=i;
        min=array[i];

        for(j=i+1;j<(length);j++) //select the min of the rest of array
        {
            if(min>array[j])   //ascending order for descending reverse
            {
                minLoc=j;  //the position of the min element 
                min=array[j];
            }
        }

        int temp=array[i] ;
        array[i]=array[minLoc];  //swap 
        array[minLoc]=temp;

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            cout<<array[i]<<endl;

        //return 1;
      }

        delete []array;

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?

Comment: I don't know much about passing data between programs in memory, but two things seem odd to me : 1. Why do you start another program for this? Why not implement a method in your program to do it? 2. It seems to me that if you do the 'delete [] array' right before returning you would destroy your sorted array. Also, please show us, how you call this fragment, especially how you initialise the '*array'.

Comment: main program is used to select an different exe when requires.so have to do it seperately.

ya,tried debugging, error occurred in the line ' min=array[i] '

Comment: So please, show us how you create the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code. First one is, there must be at least 10 elements in your array, so that the logging you do at the end does not crash your program. The second is that you delete an array that was allocated elsewhere. This is usually problematic and probably the reason of the error. You should look look up passing memory between executables.